# What is the best way to recall information from multiple activities (Android)?

Tags: android, database, variables, android-activity

I'm making a game for the Android platform and I need to access some information from multiple activities (achievements, sound on/off, etc). I know I can pass individual values from one activity to another, but is there a way I can set up like a database or something where I can access the variables from any activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your app requirement. Usually the data are shared between 2 activities via,
"Extras sent as part of the intent"

If you like to share the data across multiple activities then  you could use,
1. Preference - Using application preference (XML file stored in app directory)
2. Databases - Using Android Content provider/resolver

Comment: Can you explain the preference? I've tried to use it, but I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use SQLite to persist data. There are other alternatives: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html It really depends on how complex the data is. Another approach is pass data between activities as Serializable or Parcelable objects, but if you want to be able to query data anew from any activity you'll need a sqlite db or some sort of mechanism to serialize data and write it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.  You could set up an SQLite database, use SharedPreferences, or use startActivityForResult() in combination with an Intent.  All of these are well documented in the Developer's site if you want to research them.

Comment: startActivityForResult has to do with the specific case of starting an Activity and having the "calling" activity get the results back from it. In general, all you need is startActivity(new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class).putSerializableExtra("foo", someSerializableObject)));

Comment: He said that he needs to access data from other activities, not just send data to them.  Doing it with startActivityForResult() would allow him to pass in a flag and then receive data back based on what flag he sent, which is what the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference as easy way to do this.

The docs says:

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows
>   you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data
>   types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data:
>   booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist
>   across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

Following is the code from the docs:

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

For other ways to store data there is very good tutorials on android site- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/index.html